# CSS flexbox not respecting vertical maximum when nested

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve a layout like this using flexbox:

```
---------------------
|                   |
---------------------
|     |             |
|     |             |
|     |             |
---------------------
|                   |
---------------------
```

I started with a simplified version:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="content">
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

The key point here is that the `content` div scrolls internally. Now I want to implement another flex-container like this:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue">           
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Now the behavior changes and the red div on the bottom disappears because the central div takes as much space as is needed by the `content`.

How can I change the behavior so that the `content` does not pushes away

Comment: It is still there. Perhaps you didn't scroll till the end.

Comment: I know. I want the bottom red to behave like in the first snippet. Without scrolling.

Comment: Remove the `overflow:scroll` from the outer div and set a fixed height for the inner div.

Comment: I cant remove it from the content div because I want it to scroll and not to stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* added */
}

.green {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue">           
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.blue`. If not added the scroll behavior in `.content` won't activate because its parent would stretch to fit the content.

Comment: `min-height:0;` Instead

Comment: @ZohirSalak hmmm. This also works, but I don't see why. Would you care to explain what's happening under the hood? This wouldn't be my preferred approach but I'm just surprised it works at all.

Comment: That is actually the right approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/7148391 overflow auto or scroll works because it also ignores children's size

Comment: Ah, I see. That actually makes a lot of sense. My answer was written without knowledge of this default behavior, so I would say it's easier to understand. But I do admit setting min-height should be the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.blue {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 80vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue">           
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Set `max-height` on `.content`. That way it doesn't matter what the height of any other elements around it is, it will still scroll how you want.

*EDIT*

Better yet, add it to `.blue`.

Comment: To what value should I set it. i want the site to behave exactly as in the first snippet but simply with a nested flex. setting the height to a fixed value would meen to leave the purpose of flexbox.

Comment: Setting `max-height` doesn't mean setting the actual height of the `div`, it just means that the height won't extend beyond whatever height you set and `overflow: scroll` will still work.

Comment: As to what value, it's up to you. However high you want the `div`s max-height to be.